# Использование трюка при написании формулы интеграла в Word

Tags: ms-word, формулы

В документе Word используются формулы вычисления определенного интеграла по формуле Ньютона-Лейбница:
[image: Определенный интеграл]

Вопрос. Некрасиво отображается вертикальная черта с границами интеграла. Как можно улучшить, например, индексы?

Comment: А как хотелось?

Comment: Уменьшить индексы при вертикальной черте

Answer (score 1):

Вставляешь вертикальную черту с пустым квадратом справа, справа к ней делаешь нижний индекс ("_a<пробел>"), потом квадрат ("^b<пробел>), получается как нужно.